# How To Hide Certain Warnings In XCode 7

Tags: xcode

These warnings about unused variables are driving me crazy. How do I hide them? I've tried turning them off in my project info, both for debug and release. [image]

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why, oh why, would you ever want to *hide* those warnings...? At least let Xcode tell you when you are in dire need of code cleanup. They are your friend.

Comment: @StephenPaul They're very handy, I agree. But I don't want them to be persistent. When I open a variable and don't use it for a few minutes I don't want that yellow bar on my screen. I would much prefer to be able to switch it off and then switch it back on and have a "cleaning session" instead of all of these non-immediate warnings clogging up interface. The instant a variable is opened that thing pops up. It's very annoying.